# without username filed user only enter password! How

Tags: joomla3.0

I have design a page where every time user go to page `submit a code` after entering a code or password then access all other website pages.

I know rest of work is achieved through `Access Control List` means only logged in users can access.

Now I need page where you can enter only password without enter username.

Here is an example [click here](http://www.imperialroi.com/verify/index.php)

Currently this page is non joomla page ..rest of the site is joomla based.

How can I edit login page so that login page only have password filed.

also when user close browser he logout automatically

requirement is only one code is used thorough out the website for every user ....

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Got to this directory

```
 components/com_users/views/login/tmpl
```

Find `default_login.php` and modify it as per your usage. Make sure you are checking in active template directory.